# Finding Common Sets of data by comparing sub-details

Tags: sql, t-sql, group-by, pivot, grouping

I have a table which details the sales details, the product and quantity with some other details, shown below.

```sql
SalesOrderID    ProductID   OrderQty
           1          762          1
           1          758          1
           2          760          1
           3          710          3
           3          773          1
           3          778          1
           3          775          1
           4          747          1
           5          710          1
           5          709          2
           5          773          2
           5          776          1
           6          762          1
           6          758          1
```

I am trying to **`mark / group`** sales orders which are same i.e. they have the same list of `ProductID` with the same `OrderQty`. For example, in the above case, `SalesOrderID` with `1` and `6` are for instance the same.

I have, so far, tried to group the data by the combination of `ProductID` & `OrderQty` and then tried to sum over `SalesOrderID`, but clearly this is not a reliable solution.

```sql
With TempView as (
  Select SalesOrderID, ProductID, OrderQty,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY ProductID, OrderQty) as 'RANK_P_W_Q'
    FROM SalesRecords
), SumBySalesID as (
  Select SalesOrderID, ProductID, OrderQty, SUM(RANK_P_W_Q)
    OVER(PARTITION BY SalesOrderID ORDER BY SalesOrderID 
     ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) as 'SalesMarker'
  FROM TempView
) Select SalesOrderID, ProductID, OrderQty,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY SalesMarker) as 'SalesGroup'
    FROM SumBySalesID
```

The next solution would be to pivot, the table along `ProductID` and then it would be a straight forward, to group by `SalesOrderID`, but, I cannot rely on this stratergy because, Pivot would usually result to have more than `1024` columns, which is the limit for normal tables.I know about `wide-tables` but I don't want to go that route as I have to manage the data length along the rows, by `8,096 Bytes` and I would like to keep the script as simple as possible.

I hope somebody could point me in the right direction.

Comment: what version of mssql?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza MSSql 2016

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MSSQL 2017 just use `STRING_AGG` function, 2016 check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591490/how-to-make-a-query-with-group-concat-in-sql-server?noredirect=1&lq=1) how emulate it.

**[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d2913/11)**

First create a key for each order with products and quantities.

```
SELECT [SalesOrderID]
     , STRING_AGG (CAST([ProductID] as nvarchar(100))  
                 + '-' 
                 + CAST([OrderQty] as nvarchar(100)), ',')  
                 WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY [ProductID] ASC) AS csv  
FROM Sales
GROUP BY [SalesOrderID];
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| SalesOrderID |                     csv |
|--------------|-------------------------|
|            1 |             762-1,758-1 |
|            2 |                   760-1 |
|            3 | 710-3,773-1,778-1,775-1 |
|            4 |                   747-1 |
|            5 | 710-1,709-2,773-2,776-1 |
|            6 |             762-1,758-1 |
```

Then group each key together to find duplicates:

```
with cte as (
  SELECT [SalesOrderID]
       , STRING_AGG (CAST([ProductID] as nvarchar(100))  
                   + '-' 
                   + CAST([OrderQty] as nvarchar(100)), ',')  
                   WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY [ProductID] ASC) AS csv
  FROM Sales
  GROUP BY [SalesOrderID]
) 
SELECT *, rank() over (ORDER BY csv) as grp
FROM CTE
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| SalesOrderID |                     csv | grp |
|--------------|-------------------------|-----|
|            5 | 710-1,709-2,773-2,776-1 |   1 |
|            3 | 710-3,773-1,778-1,775-1 |   2 |
|            4 |                   747-1 |   3 |
|            2 |                   760-1 |   4 |
|            1 |             762-1,758-1 |   5 |
|            6 |             762-1,758-1 |   5 |
```