# SQL Server mulitple results to one row by ID (Version 2012)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Consider this query and result set:

```
Select udbA.userId, d.dbName
from user_db_access udbA
Inner join dbList d on d.dbid = udbA.dbid 
Order By udbA.userId
```

1   az

1   nc_west

1   bsc_mo

1   NS_002

What I am looking for is a way to flatten this into one record.  I know I can do it with a temp table and select into, but I was curious to see if a query could do it directly.  A user could have up to 15 databases available to them.

Looking for results like below ( 2 columns -- userid and the database names ):

userid  dbname

1       az nc_west bsc_mo NS_002

SQL Server Version:  Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP3) (KB3072779) - 11.0.6020.0 (X64)   Oct 20 2015 15:36:27   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3  (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: How many items will you have per `userId`? Is it fixed, does it have a max or unlimited?

Comment: I added on my answer reference on how to achieve it in older versios: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591490/how-to-make-a-query-with-group-concat-in-sql-server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want a space-delimited list of database names:

```
DECLARE @Access table ( userId int, dbName varchar(50) );
INSERT INTO @Access VALUES
    ( 1, 'az' ), ( 1, 'nc_west' ), ( 1, 'bsc_mo' ), ( 1, 'NS_002' );

SELECT DISTINCT
    ax.userId, db.list
FROM @Access AS ax
OUTER APPLY (

    SELECT LTRIM ( (
        SELECT ' ' + dbName AS "text()" FROM @Access AS x WHERE x.userId = ax.userId
            FOR XML PATH ( '' )
    ) ) AS list

) AS db;
```

Returns

```
+--------+--------------------------+
| userId |           list           |
+--------+--------------------------+
|      1 | az nc_west bsc_mo NS_002 |
+--------+--------------------------+
```

For a comma-delimited list:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    ax.userId, db.list
FROM @Access AS ax
OUTER APPLY (

    SELECT STUFF ( (
        SELECT ',' + dbName AS "text()" FROM @Access AS x WHERE x.userId = ax.userId
            FOR XML PATH ( '' )
    ), 1, 1, '' ) AS list

) AS db;
```

Returns

```
+--------+--------------------------+
| userId |           list           |
+--------+--------------------------+
|      1 | az,nc_west,bsc_mo,NS_002 |
+--------+--------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `GROUP BY` and `row_number` as follows:

```
select userId,
       max(case when rn = 1 then dbName end) as val1,
       max(case when rn = 2 then dbName end) as val2,
       max(case when rn = 3 then dbName end) as val3,
       max(case when rn = 4 then dbName end) as val4
  from
(Select udbA.userId, d.dbName, 
        row_number() over (partition by udbA.userId order by d.dbName) as rn
   from user_db_access udbA
   Inner join dbList d on d.dbid = udbA.dbid ) t
group by userId
```

**-- update**

You just need two columns then use the `STRING_AGG` as follows:

```
Select udbA.userId, 
       string_agg(d.dbName, ' ') within group (order by d.dbName) as dbName 
  from user_db_access udbA
 Inner join dbList d on d.dbid = udbA.dbid
group by udbA,userId
```

**-- For SQL server 2012**

```
Select distinct udbA.userId, 
STUFF((SELECT distinct '' + d.dbName
         from dbList d
         where d.dbid = udbA.dbid
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,0,'') AS dbid
FROM user_db_access udbA
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbList d
         where d.dbid = udbA.dbid)
```

Or use CTE as follows:

```
with CTE as
(Select udbA.userId, d.dbName
   from user_db_access udbA
   Inner join dbList d on d.dbid = udbA.dbid)
Select distinct c.userId, 
    STUFF((SELECT distinct '' + cc.dbName
             from cte cc
             where c.dbid = cc.dbid
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
            ,1,0,'') AS dbid
    FROM cte c
```

Comment: Looking for 2 columns

Comment: string agg not available in sql server 2012 apparently :-(

Comment: the 2012 option did not work for me.  it produces results 1 row per user per database.

Comment: use Distinct as updated in the answer or use CTE as added in the answer

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your SQL Server version you can use [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Like this:

```
Select udbA.userId, string_agg(d.dbName, ', ') as name
  from user_db_access udbA
        Inner join dbList d on d.dbid = udbA.dbid 
  group by udbA.userId
```

If you are using an older version you already have answers here: [How to make a query with group_concat in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591490/how-to-make-a-query-with-group-concat-in-sql-server)

Like this:

```
select
    udbA.userId,
    stuff((
        select cast(',' as varchar(max)) + d.dbName
          from dbList d
         where d.dbid = udbA.dbid
         order by d.dbName
       for xml path('')), 1, 1, '') as dbList
from
    user_db_access udbA 
      inner join dbList dl on dl.dbid = udbA.dbid 
order by
    udbA.userId;
```

Comment: Are you able to provide an example with the query above?

Comment: @Neo added above

Comment: I am getting multiple results per user id with NULLS as some of the database names

Comment: Are there userId with no database associated to it ?

Comment: its possible yes.  ( access removed versus the user )

Comment: Ok, added a join on the outer query, that should prevent the nulls

Comment: getting this error now *Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 43
Invalid object name 'dbList'.*

Comment: That's weird... it is just a simple join, exact the same as the original query? Essentially the error message is saying that `dbList` table does not exist to be joined at.

Comment: My bad I fat fingered a character, so no error.  However I am getting multiple rows per user / database names versus 1 row containing all.

Comment: hmmm that's because of the join... changing it to an exists should work. But I will leave it as is since the accepted answer is better anyways :)