# How to concatenate CommaSeperator in sqlserver

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a Parameter as

```
@Cols='[Development Opportunities],[Feedback and Coaching],[Goals and Targets Set]'
```

I want the result set as below:

```
sum(isnull([Development Opportunities],0)) as [Development Opportunities],
sum(isnull([Feedback and Coaching],0)) as [Feedback and Coaching],
sum(isnull([Goals and Targets Set],0)) as [Goals and Targets Set]
```

Any ideas? Parameter values are generated dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using [dynamic sql](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx). So you should make a SQL statement and run it using [sp_executesql](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx)

First of all we should separate this list to rows and then concatenate them with format we need to generate a SQL statement. Both tasks we can do using XML SQL server features.

To separate this string to elements we use [nodes() Method of XML data type](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx).

To use it we should convert this string to XML format. Just replace `,` with `</X><X>`:

```
DECLARE @X XML
SET @X = CAST('<X>'+REPLACE(@Cols,',','</X><X>')+'</X>' as XML)
```

Then using `nodes()` split this string to elements:

```
  SELECT a.c.value('data(.)', 'VARCHAR(100)') as fieldName
    FROM   @X.nodes('X') as a(c)
```

Then we should concatenate result set to one line formatting it as we need. We use [XML PATH()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6899/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-sql-server-function-to-join-multiple-rows-from-a-su)

```
SELECT @SQL = STUFF
((SELECT ',sum(isnull('+fieldName+',0)) as '+ fieldName
    FROM  separatedTable
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.','NVARCHAR(max)')
,1,1,'')
```

Now format the full SQL statement and run it:

```
SET @SQL='SELECT '+@SQL+ ' FROM YOUR_TABLE'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL
```

Notice that for `sp_executesql` a command line parameter has to be `NVARCHAR()` type not just `VARCHAR()`.

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/28113/19)</kbd>

And here is a full code:

```
DECLARE @Cols varchar(100)
SET @Cols = '[Development Opportunities],[Feedback and Coaching],[Goals and Targets Set]'

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @X XML

SET @X = CAST('<X>'+REPLACE(@Cols,',','</X><X>')+'</X>' as XML)

;WITH separatedTable AS 
(
  SELECT a.c.value('data(.)', 'VARCHAR(100)') as fieldName
    FROM   @X.nodes('X') as a(c)
) 
SELECT @SQL = STUFF
((SELECT ',sum(isnull('+fieldName+',0)) as '+ fieldName
    FROM  separatedTable
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.','NVARCHAR(max)')
,1,1,'')

SET @SQL='SELECT '+@SQL+ ' FROM YOUR_TABLE'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL
```

**And last but not least**: "Run time-compiled Transact-SQL statements can expose applications to malicious attacks, such as SQL injection". So you should [check your input parameter list to prevent injection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953(SQL.105).aspx).