# Getting Data separated by comma,

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have one table like this..

```
TicketID    Name   

111         ABC
111         DEF
222         GHI
333         ABC
333         GHI
```

I need output like this..

```
TicketID    Name   

111         ABC, DEF
222         GHI
333         ABC, GHI
```

I have found a same kind of query try to do it with Stuff function but don't know why m not getting exact result 
Can anyone give me query for SQL Server.. n tell me how actually it process.

Comment: this has got to be a duplicate.

Comment: Please add the query you tried to the question.

Comment: If you have a query that doesn't work, you should include that in your question.  We cannot read your mind in trying to explain why it doesn't work.

Comment: yeah u r right.. I thought it would be good if I ask for query then understand it. its ok

Comment: or better duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/a/6980/659190

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/273330/659190), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6980/659190) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/451441/659190).

```
SELECT 
  [TicketId],
  STUFF((
    SELECT ', ' + [Name]) 
    FROM [OneTable] 
    WHERE ([TicketId] = OT.[TicketId]) 
    FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)')
  ,1,2,'') AS Name
FROM [OneTable] OT
GROUP BY [TicketId]
```

Go and vote it up, then close this question.

Comment: thank bro..got it...I was not doing group by and not had where command in the stuff function..thanx alot