# Transpose row results to single row

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Perhaps my example is too simple but I need to transpose the results from being multiple rows to being multiple columns in a single row. The only issue that the number of returned initial rows may vary so therefore my final number of columns may vary also.

As an example, my returned results from

```
select name from pets
```

could be:

Dog

Cat

Fish

Rabbit

And I need each value in a separate column:

`Dog`   `Cat`   `Fish`   `Rabbit`

Comment: It is probably better to do this transformation in the application, rather than in the database.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to create a SQL Server function to "join" multiple rows from a subquery into a single delimited field?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6899/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-sql-server-function-to-join-multiple-rows-from-a-su)

Comment: The concept is called pivoting, plenty of questions answered on SO. However, SQL Server does not allow dynamic pivoting. Anecdotally, MS Access does (using the TRANSFORM statement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
-- First create list of columns that you need in end result
SET @columns = N''
SELECT @columns += N', ' + QUOTENAME(name)
FROM (select distinct name from pets) AS x     


-- now create pivot statement as:

SET @sql = N'
SELECT ' + STUFF(@columns, 1, 2, '') + '
FROM
(
  SELECT name
   FROM pets   
) AS j
PIVOT
(
  max(name) FOR name IN ('
  + STUFF(REPLACE(@columns, ', p.[', ',['), 1, 1, '')
  + ')
) AS p;'


EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a4b6e9/10)</kbd>