# Using COALESCE directly within a SELECT to return comma separated values from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to retrieve a list of comma separated product categories for a product.

**Here is an idea of what I am trying to do:**

```
SELECT *, (
  SELECT CategoryName 
  FROM ProductCategories pc 
  WHERE p.ProductId=pc.ProductId) as ProductCategories
FROM Products p
```

I need the product categories to be in a comma separated list. Is there a way to do it using COALESCE?

Comment: No, not using `coalesce()`.  But, if you google something like "SQL Server string aggregation", you'll find that this question has been asked before.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't use COALESCE to do that. COALESCE just returns the first non null argument that you pass it.

You want [How to create a SQL Server function to "join" multiple rows from a subquery into a single delimited field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6899/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-sql-server-function-to-join-multiple-rows-from-a-su)