# SQL join column within 1 table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Im busy with a script to display transactions.

I want to write an SQL query which sets everything on one line.

Here is the SQL :

```
SELECT transactienummer, code
FROM gb_kaarten 
ORDER BY transactienummer DESC
LIMIT 4
```

this is the output :

```
transactienummer code
43141            1600
43141            4410
43141            1513
43141            1514
```

I just want to have a line that looks like this :

```
transactienummer code
43141            1600        4410         1513         1514
```

I have tried some joins, but i dont seem to get it.

Thanks in forehand for the help

Comment: what type of SQL is this? MySQL?

Comment: Yes, im sorry i havent put that in the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that you are using mysql, you should do something like this:

```
SELECT transactienummer, GROUP_CONCAT(string SEPARATOR ' ') 
FROM gb_kaarten
GROUP BY code;
```

Pay attention that you will have all the result in one field separated by ''

Comment: what if he is not using MySQL :D, anyway it's a valuable answer

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @col NVARCHAR(MAX);
SELECT @col = COALESCE(@col + char, '') +Code 
  FROM gb_kaarten

select transactienummer,@col 
from gb_kaarten
group by transactienummer
```

NOTE: It will works only for one common type

Answer (score 0):

You can find this in SO Link below

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6980/4701699

In your case find the try this

```
SELECT distinct [transactienummer]
,(STUFF((SELECT CAST('   ' + Code AS VARCHAR(MAX)) 
     FROM Table
     WHERE (transactienummer= Table.transactienummer) 
     FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 2, '')) AS Code
FROM Table
```

Find the solution in Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f8339/1