# Using TSQL how to Group By a Value and create a delimited string of ID

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by

Using TSQL Group by how to get from

```
Id value

    1  a
    2  b
    3  b
```

To

```
Ids Value Quantity
1    a    1
2,3  b    2
```

Comment: There is no 'simple' way to get a 'string concat aggregate' in TSQL. Approaches involved XML and string manipulation and CLR UDFs. There are many duplicates.

Comment: Maybe better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6899/how-to-create-a-sql-server-function-to-join-multiple-rows-from-a-subquery-into

Comment: And see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131056.aspx for a CLR UDF