# SQL - summarize all Product Types from a list of Authorized

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, summary

I'm trying to figure out how to display the TYPES of orders each client can place with us. We have the following tables CLIENTS, CLIENT_SERVICE_TYPE, SERVICE_TYPES, PRODUCT_TYPE

We have many service types which can be easily associated with Fruits and Vegetables.

> CLIENTS - Lists all our clients
>    CLIENT_SERVICE_TYPE - lists all of the service types (Apples, Pears, Bananas, Squash, Chicken) they are authorized to place.
>    SERVICE_TYPES - lists the hundreds and hundreds of fruits and vegetables we offer (Of which, each client can only order a select few from.
>    PRODUCT_TYPE lists the 5 categories we offer (IE Fruits, Vegetables, Spices, Dairy, Meat)

I want to be able to create a summary report that will display certain Clients like this

Company Name | Sales Rep  | **Product Types**
Company ABC  | Jane Smith | **Fruits**
Company XYZ  | Joe Aardvark | **Vegetables, Fruits**
Company 123  | Amy Addams | **Meat, Vegetables, Fruits**

In the above example, Company ABC has 15 authorized Fruits (Bananas, Apples, Oranges, etc) but its summarized as 1 on one line **Fruits**.  Company XYZ has the same 15 authorized fruits and 1 carrot.  I want it to show up (order doesn't matter) as  **Vegetables, Fruits** on the same line.  Company 123 is authorized for only 4 services (Chicken, Bananas, Peas and Squash).  **Meat, Vegetables, Fruits**

I know this is probably simple to find existing tutorials on, but my terminology is obviously not up to par.  This is as far as I got and as you can probably guess, it's showing up multiple lines for the X amount of service types they are approved for.

```
SELECT
    company [Client Name]
    ,salesperson [Sales Rep]
    --,pt.productTypeName [List of approved Product Types]
    FROM CLIENT cl (NOLOCK)
        LEFT JOIN
    CLIENT_SERVICE_TYPE cst (NOLOCK) = cl.client_key = cst.client_key
        LEFT JOIN
    SERVICE_TYPE st (NOLOCK) = cst.service_key = st.service_key
        LEFT JOIN
    PRODUCT_TYPE pt (NOLOCK) = cst.productTypeId = pt.productTypeId
WHERE cl.client_program_id in (1,2,3)
    and status = 160
ORDER BY company
```

Comment: Have you tried `GROUP BY`? And if you need multiple row values in a single column you will probably also need a `PIVOT` or subquery.

Comment: I tried the Group By and that seems get part of what I want accomplished but not all.  
in my example above, the results turn like like this  

Company XYZ | Joe Aardvark | **Vegetables**   
Company XYZ | Joe Aardvark | **Fruits**

Comment: I found a [promising link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6899/how-to-create-a-sql-server-function-to-join-multiple-rows-from-a-subquery-into) where I can combine the data into one value using a GROUP BY at the end. It doesn't quite do 100% of what I wanted to do but damn if it isn't close enough

Comment: use INNERMJOIN and GROUP BY then show us the output

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer through trial and error.  Within a SELECT statement, this is how I did it

```
SELECT
company as [Company Name]
,salesperson as [Sales Rep]
,(STUFF((SELECT CAST(', ' + productTypeName AS VARCHAR(MAX))
    FROM CLIENT_SERVICE_TYPE cst
        LEFT JOIN
    SERVICE_TYPE st on cst.service_type_key = st.service_type_key
        LEFT JOIN
    PRODUCT_TYPE pt on st.product_type_key = pt.product_type_key
    WHERE c.client_key = cst.client_key
    GROUP BY pt.product_type_name
    FOR XML PATH ('')),1,2, '')) [Product Types]
FROM CLIENT c
```

The end results
**Company Name | Sales Rep    | Product Types**
Company ABC  | Jane Smith   | *Fruits*
Company XYZ  | Joe Aardvark | *Vegetables, Fruits*
Company 123  | Amy Addams   | *Meat, Vegetables, Fruits*