# Standard SQL in BigQuery - Get concatenate text from multiple rows

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have tables like:

document:

```
+-----+---------+
| dId | score   |
+-----+---------+
| A   | 100     |
| B   | 80      |
| C   | 70      |
+-----+---------+
```

entity:

```
+------+------------+-----+
| name | details    | dId |
+------+------------+-----+
| e1   | a          |   A |
| e2   | a          |   A |
| e3   | b          |   B |
| e4   | c          |   B |
| e5   | d          |   C |
+------+------------+-----+
```

Expected Output:

```
+------+--------+----------+
| dId  | score  | entities |
+------+--------+----------+
| A    | 100    |   e1, e2 |
| B    | 80     |   e3, e4 |
| C    | 70     |   e5     |
+------+--------+----------+
```

Current Query:

```
SELECT
  docT.dId,
  docT.score,
  entityT.name AS entities
FROM
  document docT,
  entity entityT
LEFT JOIN
  document_sentiment docT1
ON
  docT1.dId = entityT.dId
```

Now, I've gone through [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/how-to-concatenate-text-from-multiple-rows-into-a-single-text-string-in-sql-serv) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6899/how-to-create-a-sql-server-function-to-join-multiple-rows-from-a-subquery-into) which are for SQL-Server.

But I'm looking for [Standard SQL Format used by BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/).

How can I get the expected output with Standard SQL format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like  below

```
  select d.dId,score,STRING_AGG(e.name) 
 document d join entity e on d.did=e.did
  group by d.dId,score
```

Answer (score 1):

use `array_agg()` - [reference](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aggregate_functions)

```
SELECT
  docT.dId,
  docT.score,
  array_agg(entityT.name) AS entities
FROM
document docT join entity entityT on docT.dId=entityT.dId
LEFT JOIN document_sentiment docT1 ON docT1.dId = entityT.dId
group by docT.dId,docT.score
```