# Display column values rowwise in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, string-aggregation

Can we have the column values displayed rowwise separated by commas. For example, the below returns a column. Can we make the expected output happen

```
select [name] as database_name
from sys.databases
```

Actual output

```
database_name
db1
db2
db3
```

Expected output

```
database_name
db1, db2, db3
```

Comment: Which SQL Server version?

Comment: 2012...........

Comment: Please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6899/how-to-create-a-sql-server-function-to-join-multiple-rows-from-a-subquery-into

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to concatenate text from multiple rows into a single text string in SQL server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/how-to-concatenate-text-from-multiple-rows-into-a-single-text-string-in-sql-serv)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use FOR XML PATH to concatenate column values:

```
SELECT name = STUFF((
            SELECT ',' + NAME
            FROM sys.databases
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 1, '')
```

Comment: . . Drop the `FROM` clause is in the outer query.